# Detecting ctrl+tab keypress

Tags: .net, vb.net, keypress

How do I detect a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress?

Reason for asking: I want to stop a user from changing tabs in a tab control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering key messages isn't very productive.  You would also have to filter <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PageDn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>.  Just prevent tab changes by implementing the Selecting event.  Like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private allowTabChanges As Boolean

    Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
        If Not allowTabChanges then e.Cancel = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Set allowTabChanges to true and back to false in any of your own code that wants to change the active tab page.  The key filtering method is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872972/c-tab-switching-in-tabcontrol/1874512#1874512).

Comment: Thank you! The selecting event was exactly what I needed! [I also like that you got the real question, and _also_ linked to a solution for my title question]