# RadTabControl, switching between tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, rad-controls

I have a RadTabControl control with two tabs.
I would like to be able to change between them with Ctrl+Tab.

I tried with this [C# Tab switching in TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872972/c-sharp-tab-switching-in-tabcontrol), but the method ProcessCmdKey doesn't exist. I don't know why.

Could you tell me how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Tab switching in TabControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872972/c-sharp-tab-switching-in-tabcontrol)

Comment: I was try with it, but doesn't work for me.